# Google sheets, how to count "other" cells that dont match a range

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif

It's simple to count all cells that match a certain value,  but how do i could all cells that dont match one of the values within a range?

[image]

For example, how do I could cells not equal to red blue or green?

Normally you can do `=COUNTIF(A2:A10,B2)` to count ones that match a cell, but as you see from the picture it doesn't work with a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are various ways like:

```
=COUNTA(A2:A)-SUM(C2:C4)
```

or:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(A2:A, NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B))))))
```

Comment: ah damn, that top one is so clever yet simple and concise, I should have thought of that! thanks